# Speed up executable program Linux - arm processor. Bit Toggling

Tags: c, linux, embedded, toggle, executable

I'm running linux that boots into the terminal (no gui).
I have a ZyBo circuit board which has a ArmV7 processor. I wrote a C program to output a clock and a corresponding data sequence on a PMOD. The PMOD has a switching speed of up to 50MHz. However, my program's created clock only has a max frequency of 115 Hz. I need this program to output as fast as possible because the PMOD I'm using is capable of 50MHz.
I compiled my program with the following code line:
`gcc -ofast (c_program)` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 511
//________________________________________

//macro for the SIGNAL PMOD
//________________________________________
//DATA 
//ZYBO Use Pin JE1
#define INIT_SIGNAL system("echo 54 > /sys/class/gpio/export"); system("echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio54/direction");
#define SIGNAL_ON system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio54/value");
#define SIGNAL_OFF system("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio54/value");
//________________________________________

//macro for the "CLOCK" PMOD
//________________________________________
//CLOCK 
//ZYBO Use Pin JE4
#define INIT_MYCLOCK system("echo 57 > /sys/class/gpio/export"); system("echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio57/direction");
#define MYCLOCK_ON system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio57/value");
#define MYCLOCK_OFF system("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio57/value");

int main(void){

int myarray[ARRAYSIZE] = {//hard coded array for signal data
    1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    };

INIT_SIGNAL
INIT_MYCLOCK;
//infinite loop
int i;
do{
    i = 0;
    do{
        /*
        1020 is chosen because it is twice the size needed allowing for the changes in the clock.
        (511= 0-510, 510*2= 1020 ==> 0-1020 needed, so 1021 it is)
        */
        if((i%2)==0)
        {
            MYCLOCK_ON;
            if(myarray[i/2] == 1){
                SIGNAL_ON;
            }else{
                SIGNAL_OFF;
            }
        }
        else if((i%2)==1)
        {
            MYCLOCK_OFF;
            //dont need to change the signal since it will just stay at whatever it was.
        }
        ++i;
    } while(i < 1021);
} while(1);
return 0;
}
```

What can I do to make my executable program output to be at least in the magnitude of MegaHertz?

Comment: Without seeing your code and understanding what you're trying to accomplish, NOBODY can possibly help you.  The number of possible problems is huge, from bad coding to fundamental hardware limitations.  You need to do some profiling to figure out why the code is so slow.

Comment: C-Code has been added

Comment: I wouldn't think it is a hardware limitation because the the ArmV7 processor has a cpu speed of around 600MHz I think and the PMOD I'm using can hand outputs of up to about 50MHz. If I could get my data signal and my fake clock to follow the clock on my ZyBo board (or create a derived), that would be great. I'm pretty sure it is some linux configuration or knowing how to access certain things in my c-code such as the system clock

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but every one of those `system` calls carries huge overhead along with them.

Comment: I'm doing a project involving signal processing and I am using a ZyBo board to do it. The array is basically a hard-coded signal that will output on a pin on the pmod to be manipulated by other circuitry that it will connect to. 
I'm using the 'system' call to tell the system to output 1 volt or 0 volts onto a pin on the board (to represent the data signal and clock signal. One pin for the data and another for the clock). That was the only way I knew to tell the system to output a voltage. 
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are trying to toggle the *gpio* through a *pseudo-filesystem*, this involves a context switch from *user space* to kernel space and back again.  You can not do *high speed* switching like this.  Not only that, you aren't writing to the *pseudo-filesystem* directly, but loading `cat` and `echo` from disk, setting up the memory management and doing context switches between processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to control your clock by using the `system` function (i.e. create a process) to invoke another executable (`/bin/echo`) with the goal of writing values to pseudo-files in the `/sys` filesystem.  No wonder you can't achieve rates beyond the hundreds of hertz.

At the very minimum you should be writing to the pseudo-files in the `/sys` filesystem by directly opening them and writing to them from within your program, not via `system`.  This may not get you into the MHz range but it will certainly run hundreds of times faster than what you've got.

Comment: @vanjoe d'oh... too much switching back and forth between Windoze and Linux

Comment: `system` will `execve` /bin/sh which will use its internal `echo` and then you have the `waitpid`.  So definitely not a trivial round trip at these timing levels.

Answer (score 0):

Open the files directly using `FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );` and print your strings to them using `int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

if you need even more speed, look into open() system call and mmap()